# IBO and Firebird Save To Blob Field By Params

Tags: delphi, firebird

I want to save a picture from TImage to blob field by params. I've search around the net but I can't get it.

I try: params[1].LoadFromFile(PicPath). It works but I just want to stream from TImage.
Should I modified from IBO source?

```
procedure TIB_ColumnBlob.LoadFromFile( const AFileName: string );
var
  tmpStream: TStream;
begin
  tmpStream := TFileStream.Create( AFileName, fmOpenRead );
  try
    LoadFromStream( tmpStream );
  finally
    tmpStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"I've search around the net but I can't get it." - I don't know what to say  - http://www.ibobjects.com/ibocontributed.html -> http://source.ibobjects.com/contributed/IBO_JPEGdemo.zip and the description of the project below:

> A small demo project using IBO and a component TDBJPGImage based on
>   TDBImage, showing how to store images as JPG or BMP blobs with
>   on-the-fly conversion and a few other interesting options. Includes
>   sample database gbak'ed using Firebird 1.5 gbak, owner SYSDBA.

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /contributed/IBO_JPEGdemo.zip was not found on this server.